# Search numpy array inside numpy array

Tags: arrays, search, numpy

I need to find if a numpy array is inside other numpy array, but it seems to work different to python lists.
I tried to search this question in numpy documentation and internet, but not answer.
This is an example:

`import numpy as np`

```
m1=np.array([[1,2,3],[5,3,4]])
m2=np.array([5,4,3])
m2 in m1
True
m3=[[1,2,3],[5,3,4]]
m4=[5,4,3]
m4 in m3
False
```

In numpy I obtain True but with Python lists I obtain False. Is there any numpy function to make this work?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a typo in m3? Did you mean `m3 = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 4, 3]]` in place of `m3 = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 3, 4]]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the same behavior as `in` for lists, you could do something like this:

```
any(np.all(row == m2) for row in m1)
```

That does the loop over rows in python, which isn't ideal, but it should work.

To understand what's going on with the numpy `in`, here's a description of the semantics of `in` [from Robert Kern on the numpy mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/numpy-discussion@scipy.org/msg31578.html):

> It dates back to Numeric's semantics for bool(some_array), which would
>   be True if any of the elements were nonzero. Just like any other
>   iterable container in Python, `x in y` will essentially do
>
> ```
> for row in y:
>    if x == row:
>        return True
> return False
> ```
>
> Iterate along the first axis of y and compare by boolean equality. In
>   Numeric/numpy's case, this comparison is broadcasted. So that's why
>   [3,6,4] works, because there is one row where 3 is in the first
>   column. [4,2,345] doesn't work because the 4 and the 2 are not in
>   those columns.
>
> Probably, this should be considered a mistake during the transition to
>   numpy's semantics of having bool(some_array) raise an exception.
>   `scalar in array` should probably work as-is for an ND array, but
>   there are several different possible semantics for `array in array`
>   that should be explicitly spelled out, much like bool(some_array).